# Java performance problem with LinkedBlockingQueue

Tags: java, performance, multithreading, queue

this is my first post on stackoverflow... I hope someone can help me

I have a big performance regression with Java 6 `LinkedBlockingQueue`. 
In the first thread i generate some objects which i push in to the queue
In the second thread i pull these objects out. The performance regression occurs when the `take()` method of the `LinkedBlockingQueue` is called frequently.
I monitored the whole program and the `take()` method claimed the most time overall. 
And the throughput goes from ~58Mb/s to 0.9Mb/s...

the queue pop and take methods ar called with a static method from this class

```
public class C_myMessageQueue {

    private static final LinkedBlockingQueue<C_myMessageObject> x_queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<C_myMessageObject>( 50000 );

    /**
     * @param message
     * @throws InterruptedException
     * @throws NullPointerException
     */
    public static void addMyMessage( C_myMessageObject message )
            throws InterruptedException, NullPointerException {
        x_queue.put( message );
    }

    /**
     * @return Die erste message der MesseageQueue
     * @throws InterruptedException
     */
    public static C_myMessageObject getMyMessage() throws InterruptedException {
        return x_queue.take();
    }
}
```

how can I tune the `take()` method to accomplish at least 25Mb/s, or is there a other class I can use which will block when the "queue" is full or empty.

kind regards

Bart

P.S.: sorry for my bad english, I'm from Germany ;)

Comment: MB/s is meaningless. take() gets a reference. Whether the payload of that (apart from the word of the reference itself) is few bytes, or many megabytes, is irrelevant to the queue.

Comment: i know... but i tried to force the extensiveness of the regression ;)

Comment: Can you first try to add 5000 elements to the queue then run the take's to see how long each take spends?

Comment: dont you suffer from this bug if you are using JDK 6 ? http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6805775

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your producer thread simply **puts more elements than the consumer consumes**, so the queue eventually hits its capacity limit, thus the producer waits.

Consolidating my original answer since now we have basically the full picture:

- You hit the inherent throughput limit of the `LinkedBlockingQueue` (every queue has one) by doing extremely fast `put()`s, where even continual `take()s`, with zero further processing, cannot keep up. (By the way this shows that in this structure, on your JVM and machine anyway, put()s are at least slightly more costly than the reads).
- Since there is a particular lock that consumers lock, putting more consumer threads could not possibly help (if your consumer was actually doing some processing and that was bounding  the throughput, then adding more consumers would help. There are better queue implementations for a scenario with more than one consumers (or producers), you could try `SynchronousQueue`, `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, and the upcoming `TransferQueue` of jsr166y).

Some suggestions:

- Try to make more coarse-grained objects, so that the overhead of queueing each is balanced with the actual work that is offloaded from the producing thread (in your case, it seems you create much communication overhead for objects that represent negligible amounts of work)
- You could also have the producer help the consumer by offloading some consuming work (not much point in waiting idly when there is work to be done).

/updated after John W. rightly pointed out my original answer was misleading

Comment: I dont belive that a StringBuilder.append( " ----- " ); in the consumer thread is so much slower than a lot of arithmetic operations in the producer thread

Comment: Please clarify the size of the queue when the problem occurs. That's the only way we can be sure whether it's the producer or the consumer that is slow. String operations can be slow too, don't depend on such assumptions, just when you notice the problem, just check whether the queue is nearly empty or nearly full.

Comment: (I suspect though that you create very fine-grained objects unnecessarily. You might also try bundling some of those in bigger packs to decrease queue overhead, if needed).

Comment: I tried several capacitys for the queue, but the same problems occured with 20 or 50000 elements... at the moment i try the approach to transfer lists of objects with the queue.

Comment: "The same problems": please clarify the size of the queue when said problems occur.

Comment: i disabled all operations in the consumer thread, it takes only the objects from the queue, and the problems resist (the producer thread has to wait) :(

Comment: Ok, the producer waits, so the queue is full, as was my initial impression. Well, your producer creates a huge amount of objects, those arithmetic operations you mentioned aren't slow enough. You can try having more readers, as per my original answer, or create more coarse grained objects.

Comment: It sounds like if the take (consumer) is taking alot of time then the queue is empty, no? He would want to increase the number of producers

Comment: If someone tells you "take() is taking a long time", yes, you assume the queue is empty, thus you need more producers. But in fact it is full! The consumer that only ever calls take() is still too slow to keep up with that producer! The throughput of a LinkedBlockingQueue (as in any other queue) is limited by the minimum time that "take()" can take. At a stable condition, if you can't take more than X objects per time unit out, you *can't* put more than X elements (or the queue is unbounded). His producer creates more than X elements, thus it hits the inherent throughput limit of the queue.

Comment: Thats true, I just dont see how the queue being full and producers waiting has anything to do with the take spending alot of time processing.  Maybe thats your point but then your answer missleads the op to think the speed decrease by take is affected by the producers.

Comment: You are totally right, I have to modify my original answer. As you can see from the comments, the problem was rather unclear initially - my assumption had been that the consumer (and not just the take()) was slow, only later it was apparent that the bottleneck was occurring even when there was no additional processing on the consumer.

Answer (score 6):

I would generally recommend not using a LinkedBlockingQueue in a performance sensitive area of code, use an ArrayBlockingQueue.  It will giving a much nicer garbage collection profile and is more cache friendly than the LinkedBlockingQueue.

Try the ArrayBlockingQueue and measure the performance.

The only advantage of the LinkedBlockingQueue is that it can be unbounded, however this is rarely what you actually want.  If you have a case where a consumer fails and queues start backing up, having bounded queues allows the system to degrade gracefully rather risk OutOfMemoryErrors that may occur if queues are unbounded.

Comment: You're rigth, but there is only a minimal performance difference between arrayBQ and linkedBQ. and the regression still resists

Answer (score 5):

Here are a couple of things to try:

Replace the `LinkedBlockingQueue` with an `ArrayBlockingQueue`. It has no dangling references and so is better behaved when the queue fills up. Specifically, given the 1.6 implementation of LinkedBlockingQueue, full GC of the elements will not happen until the queue actually becomes empty.

If the producer side is consistently out performing the consumer side, consider using `drain` or `drainTo` to perform a "bulk" take operation.

Alternatively, have the queue take arrays or Lists of message objects. The the producer fills a List or array with message objects and each put or take moves multiple messages with the same locking overhead. Think of it as a secretary handing you a stack of "While you were out" messages vs. handing them to you one at a time.

Comment: damn, why i didn't try it my self... so i will try it now :)

Comment: I doubt the drainTo() would help. The consumer's problem is not contention for the consumer's lock (it's only a single consumer thread, taking the consumer lock is uncontended and /fast/). The fundamental issue is that the consumer is slow, less data flow through it, so the producer, no matter what (without an overflowing queue that is), is going to be bounded by that less flow - see my answer too.

Comment: ArrayBlockingQueue will be slower than LinkedBlockingQueue as it uses single lock for put() and take() whereas LinkedBlockingQueue uses 2 locks for put() and take() and synchronizes producer and consumer only when queue is empty / full.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what happens without knowing something about the filling process.

If  `addMyMessage` is called less frequently - perhaps because of a performance problem in a whole different part of your application - the `take` method has to wait.

That way it looks like `take` is the culprit, but actually it's the filling part of your application.

Comment: The filling thread is not the culprit, the filling thread wait on the consumer thread when the throughput goes down (seen with the visualvm profiler). when the filling thread had not to wait on the consumer the throughput is realy good, at least 58Mb/s. the consumer thread waits on the take method, the operations in the consumer task ar minimal... 

i tried also the ArrayBlockingQueue...the same game, the consumer wait for the slow take method, and the filler wait because the queue is full

p.s.: the program is a copy task
p.p.s: thank u for ur answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Found [this interesting post](http://tech.puredanger.com/2009/02/11/linkedblockingqueue-garbagecollection/) about performance problems due to queue size and garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that your application is affected by the locking related changes in Java 6, especially the "biased locking" feature.

Try disabling it by using the `-XX:-UseBiasedLocking` switch and see if that makes a difference.

See this for further information: [Java SE 6 Performance White Paper: Section 2.1](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/6performance.html#2.1).

Comment: Thank you for the clue, but it changed nothing... take() takes 96.7% of time in the consumer thread. in my opinion the take method is to slow...

Comment: Perhaps it helps if you look at the implementation of that method. I could not find anything weird in there.

Comment: i could not find anything to, but the fact is that take took most of time in this thread

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell anything for sure. But you can try to change `BlockingQueue` implementation (just as an experiment).

You set initial capacity 50k and use `LinkedBlockingQueue`. Try `ArrayBlockingQueue` with the same capacity, you can also play with `fair` parameter.

Comment: that will be my last try... and then i will play with javolution or something like that... or is this a bad idea?

Comment: I think he means a single-producer, single-consumer scenario, so fairness should be irrelevant. Curious that LinkedBlockingQueue doesn't expose a fair parameter though.

Answer (score 0):

If the raw performance overhead for putting and taking object from your blockingqueues is your bottleneck (and not the [slow-producer/consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem)), you can get huge performance improvements with batching of objects: For instance, instead of putting or taking fine-grained objects, you put or take coarse-grained lists of objects. Here is a code snippet:

```
ArrayBlockingQueue<List<Object>> Q = new ArrayBlockingQueue<List<Object>>();

// producer side
List<Object> l = new ArrayList<Object>();
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
    l.add(i); // your initialization here
}
Q.put(l);

// consumer side
List<Object> l2 = Q.take();
// do something
```

Batching can boost your performance by an order of magnitude.