# Execution in FixedThreadPool gets slower as time goes by

Tags: java, multithreading, collections

I have around 100000 tasks need to be done, I know that they are CPU intensive, but will only take a short execution time (When CPU is fast enough).

I use `ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);`

I choose 8 because my CPU has 8 cores.

Then to process my tasks, I loop through all of them:

```
for(Task task : tasks) {
     executor.submit(new Runnable() {
     // 1. Text analyzing
     // 2. Add result to a LinkedBlockingQueue
     }
}
```

What I observed is that for the first few thousands of task, it is really fast. But then, says after 10k tasks has been processed, the speed becomes slower, and slower...

I tried to understand but fail to figure out why it gradually becomes slower. Since when a task is done, the resource will also be freed. So I expected that the processing speed should be stable.

Then I figured out that the problem may belong to the LinkedBlockingQueue that I use to store the result from the task. But it seems that LinkedBlockingQueue provides good performance for inserting.

Can someone give me some hints or suggestions what I may do wrong in this case?

Thank you.

Comment: I dont think all the cores (8) will be free. i.e. background services, OS system also using them. Try to decrease the pool i.e. to 6

Comment: Most liklely the slow-down is the queue backing up, not the Executor itself.

Comment: Quick way to find out what the issue is to increase heap. If it moves faster than you have a data concern.

Comment: might be worth it to look at what's going on inside the VM to see if you have any memory leaks. VisualVM is free and good enough for this sort of thing: https://visualvm.java.net/

Comment: Yes you need to check the heap/the GC activity

Comment: Thank you for the memory check suggestion. I found out that the problem belongs to LinkedBlockingQueue, since the producers were a lot faster than the consumers, thus the queue had performance problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem belongs to the performance decrement of the LinkedBlockingQueue. In my case the producers were more productive in adding data to the queue while the consumers were too slow to handle.

[Java performance problem with LinkedBlockingQueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644688/java-performance-problem-with-linkedblockingqueue)

Comment: Just note, it's not a performance problem with the `Queue`. It's a concern with pulling off the queue. The `LinkedBlockiingQueue` for what is needed, will be lightning fast.